How to update a table with a new column from an excel sheet?
I am using POWERBI to visualize data, I have multiple data tables and the data is being imported from Excel. I have updated one of the Excel sheets with a new column but I have failed to update the corresponding POWERBI table. The two tables are internet_banking_data and atm_transactions_data, the error I am encountering is from the atm_transactions_data which has a unique column "TransactionStatus" that does not exist in the internet_banking_data table in POWERBI. The table I am trying to update is the "internet_banking_data" table.
Here is the error:
Load
1 query is blocked by the following error:
internet_banking_data
The column 'TransactionStatus' of the table wasn't found.


For simplicity (and just to clarify ...), you're not able to either (1) drop the column from atm_transactions_data before import, or to (2) add the missing column to your Power BI model? You could do this from Excel using PowerQuery, I believe? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-custom-column

usually when you import excel to powerbi, it will create the change type step in Power Query automatically.
you can modify that step or remove that step.

